# Is there any way in GAX to schedule skill changes for agents?

Tags: agent, contact-center

Is there any way in GAX to schedule skill changes for agents? Any thoughts appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure of any built-in scheduling capabilities for any Configuration changes available in Genesys.  But a few Genesys partners offer abilities like that. We’ve used Pointel Config Management in my previous company. You could try that as well.

Answer (score 0):

No such function is available, not even GAX has that.
You can use 3rd party software or develop your own using PSDK